# Finding a sequence of numbers in a pandas dataframe that fits certain criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sequence

Let's say we have a dataframe column that looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(1, 25, num=25)
df=pd.DataFrame(np.sin(x)* np.random.randint(10,50),columns=['Curve'])
df2=pd.DataFrame(np.linspace(4,5,num=5))
df = df['Curve'].append(df2)
df.index=(range(len(df)))
```

Now let's say we would like to locate the five numbers that we appended to the original dataframe by finding a sequence of five numbers ALL of which have an incremental difference between them that is <1. How could I go about doing this? Preferably in a way that would work on all columns within a dataframe simultaneously.

I know that in this case I've simply attached them to the end, but that is because I'm still in the process of learning how to manipulate dataframes and I'm not sure how to easily insert 5 new values in the "middle" of a column (feel free to include how to do this, it would be greatly appreciated). This is simply an illustrative example, but I would like to learn the concept to apply it to more complex datasets.

I was thinking of utilizing "if" combined with the index shift module and boolean indexing, but before I try that, I am interested in knowing if there is a more elegant and straightforward way of doing this.

Comment: are you saying you want to return every 5-number series in which the incremental difference between each number is less than 1? it is not exactly clear what it is you want to find.

Comment: @Andrew, yes that is precisely what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet below should do what you're looking for. First, check for rows less than 1.0 apart from the preceding row. In order to catch the first row of the group, do the same thing with the following row. Combine these with [np.logical_or](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html) and create group numbers by once again using shift.

Finally, filter to the groups we created that have all 'True' values; that is, every value within the group is within one of its neighbor. Once we have the all-positive groups, take the biggest one (not necessarily a group of five). Once we get that group number, return those rows from the original df.

```
df.columns = ['curve']
a = abs(df.curve - df.curve.shift()) < 1.0    
b = abs(df.curve - df.curve.shift(-1)) < 1.0  
c = np.logical_or(a, b)                       
d = (c != c.shift()).cumsum()                 
df['c'] = c
df['d'] = d

df = df.groupby(d).filter(lambda x: all(x['c']))
max_group = df.loc[df.groupby(d).cumcount().idxmax()]['d']

df_added = df.loc[df['d'] == max_group]
```

EDIT: I should also note that the concerns raised in the comments to your original question are valid.

Comment: This is probably safe, so long as the OPs `<1` actually means the absolute value is less than one. Then I'll concede that it's exceedingly unlikely for 5 consecutive rows to fit that condition (given the other data's variability) and this is probably safe. On the other hand, if it's truly only `<1` then the logic here might still work, but you wouldn't guarantee the susbet you want.

Comment: I tried your code, but got the following error code "ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional".

Could you provide a closer explanation of why you added this part `d = (c != c.shift()).cumsum() `? What value is there in finding the cumulative sum? Also, wouldn't it be better to use the np.logical_and instead? Since we need both conditions to hold true?

Comment: Can you post what a, b, and c look like as context for your error? The excerpt you posted is to assign numeric groups to the observations. No, you do not want `logical_and`; by using that, you'd lose the first and last members of the group.